# As using gerrit, how to remove remotes tag?

Tags: git, gerrit

everybody! I am using gerrit, and i met some issue.
I have created a tag which is v1.0. And I want to delete it from local and remote now. The operations have been done:

- `git tag -d v1.0`
- `git push origin refs/tags/v1.0`

Then , I met a error:  `! [remote rejected] v1.0 (cannot delete references)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://admin@review.thomas.com:29418/testproject'`

What's wrong with it ?

Comment: Likely you have to have `delete tags` permission.

Comment: gerrit has its own set of permissions and options for fine grained project administration. So ask your gerrit admin or in case it's you who administrates the installation, check the settings more thouroughly.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have connected gerrit admin. And gerrit admin grained me permissions for pushing tag. Then i try it again, it works.

Comment: Keep in mind that Git won't update existing tags in the local repository if they change upstream. In other words, those who downloaded your original v1.0 tag will not see your new tag and you no longer have an unambiguous definition of the tag. That's a bad situation to be in.

Comment: Ok, i get it. thank you , @MagnusBäck.

Answer (score 7):

To delete or overwrite an existing tag, grant (set "ALLOW") "Push" permission with the "Force Push" option enabled for reference name refs/tags/*.

Comment: It's also possible this way. See more info about the two ways in the Gerrit documentation: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_delete

Comment: In a case I encountered today, I could not delete the tag through the command line, even with the correct permission. I had to use the Gerrit administrative interface: top menu option `Projects > Tags`