# How can I delete a remote tag in eGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I can remove a local tag very easy in the *Git Repositories View* of eclipse.

But if that tag was a remote tag (originally) and I make a *push* - nothing happens. On the next *pull* that tag will reappear again.

Neither `Remote` -> `Push tags` nor `Remote` -> `Push` -> `Add all tag specs` removed that tag from origin. And I've tried `Add delete ref specification` in the same dialog, but Eclipse won't let me add `tag-name` or `:refs/tags/tag-name`.

I know that I can use the command line, as described in "[How to delete a git remote tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-remote-git-tag)", but I didn't find a way to do it from eGit.

Comment: Have you tried with `Team` -> `Remote` -> `Push...` and `Add All Tags Spec` ?

Comment: I've updated my question: Yes I've tried that. But playing with `Remote`  -> `Push` I finally found the solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Playing with `Team` -> `Remote` -> `Push` I found the solution.

I have to enter in `Remote ref to delete:`

```
refs/tags/my-tag-name
```

and add that to the specifications to push. When I finish the dialog the tag is removed from remote.

The same applies, if I just click `Add All Tags Spec` (or something else that creates a new row in `Specifications to push`), click on the `Mode` column to convert the `Update` into a `Delete` and enter the correct ref from above into the `Destination Ref` column.

Funny thing: The tag is not offered if I open the drop down of `Remote ref to delete`, but if I use `Ctrl`+`Space` I can choose from the list of tags (and branches) and it generates the correct ref spec.

Comment: Thank you!  It's crazy we can add tags from Team -> Advance -> Tag, but we can't delete them from there!

Comment: Alternatively, you can put your cursor in the `Remote ref to delete:` block, then click CTRL+SPACE and select the tag you want to delete (The tags are below the branches).

Comment: If you read my _whole_ answer you will notice that I found this already by myself.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. If you're using Gerrit, you can get some additional help on setting the right authorizations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017325/as-using-gerrit-how-to-remove-remotes-tag