# Gerrit access controls delete branch or tag by project owner

Tags: gerrit

In gerrit version 2.16, does a user who is a member of the Project Owners group (i.e., who has been granted Owner permission) automatically have the privileges/rights to delete a branch or tag?

The gerrit access control guide https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html (currently showing version 3.1.2) and the SO answer
[As using gerrit, how to remove remotes tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017325/as-using-gerrit-how-to-remove-remotes-tag/31075846) both state that only users with Push + Force permission on reference `refs/tags/*` can delete a tag.

I checked my repo and the All-Projects parent. My repo grants me Owner permission. I do not have Delete Reference permissions.  All-Projects grants owners on namespace `refs/tags/*` ALLOW for `Allow pushing (but not force pushing)`.  The transcript below shows I can delete tags, which seems like it contradicts the doc.

```
% git tag "delete-me"
% git tag
1.3.0
delete-me
% git push origin delete-me 
Enumerating objects: 89, done.
Counting objects: 100% (89/89), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
Writing objects: 100% (51/51), 5.23 KiB | 1.74 MiB/s, done.
Total 51 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (20/20)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://gerrit.obfuscated-forgive-me.org:29418/my/project.git
 * [new tag]         delete-me -> delete-me
% git tag -d delete-me
Deleted tag 'delete-me' (was 85013e4)
% git push origin :delete-me
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://gerrit.obfuscated-forgive-me.org:29418/my/project.git
 - [deleted]         delete-me
```

The access guide gives hints about blocking tag deletes, but doesn't really make it clear: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#_make_sure_no_one_can_update_or_delete_a_tag

Update 1 - Results of testing with an annotated tag:

```
% git tag -a "delete-me-annotate"
   ..enter annotation comment in editor, save, exit..
% git tag
1.3.0
delete-me-annotate
% git push origin delete-me-annotate
Enumerating objects: 90, done.
Counting objects: 100% (90/90), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done.
Writing objects: 100% (52/52), 5.38 KiB | 1.79 MiB/s, done.
Total 52 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (20/20)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://gerrit.obfuscated-forgive-me.org:29418/my/project.git
 * [new tag]         delete-me-annotate -> delete-me-annotate
% git tag -d delete-me-annotate
Deleted tag 'delete-me-annotate' (was c854646)
% git push origin :delete-me-annotate
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://gerrit.obfuscated-forgive-me.org:29418/my/project.git
 - [deleted]         delete-me-annotate
```

Comment: You create/delete a lightweight tag (see "git help tag" for details). Please repeat your test with a annotated tag (git tag -a "delete-me") and tell if you get the same result.

Comment: Thanks @MarceloÁviladeOliveira for the suggestion, test results added above.  Works equally well for annotated tags.